# Compute - Coefficient Extraction

Tags: generating-functions

I need to compute the nth coefficient from the following expression.

$[z^n]\frac{z+z^2}{\sqrt[3]{1-2z}}$

How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)  for $|-2z|<1,$

$$(1-2z)^{-1/3}=1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{1\cdot4\cdot(3r-1)}{3^r}(2z)^r=1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty1\cdot4\cdot(3r-1)\left(\dfrac23\right)^rz^r$$

So, $z^n, n\ge3$ in $$(z+z^2)(1-2z)^{-1/3}$$  will be $$\left(1\cdot4\cdot(3r-1)\left(\dfrac23\right)^r\right)_{r=n-1}+\left(1\cdot4\cdot(3r-1)\left(\dfrac23\right)^r\right)_{r=n-2}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting the first equation from Binomial series.

Comment: I don't understand how you received the first equation.

Comment: @DSan, Are you talking about the Binomial Series, then please refer to the link